# Dont refresh view in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Created a small game "Snake". When the application is launched, everything works as it should. While the game is going on, I click on the "New Game" button and the whole field freezes, although I see that he goes where he needs to in cycles.

I use ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection>.

ViewModel code:

```
    public Field()
    {
        _rnd = new Random();

        StartCommand = new Command(Start, canExecuteMethod);

        InitGame();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void InitGame()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)
        };
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;

        _gameState = GameState.Begin;
        Direction = Direction.Right;
        NewDirection = Direction.Right;

        _headX = _columns / 2;
        _headY = _rows / 2;

        GameField = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
        {
            GameField.Add(new ObservableCollection<Cell>());
            for (int j = 0; j < _columns; j++)
            {
                GameField[i].Add(new Cell(0, _colors[0]));
            }
        }

        GameField[_headY][_headX].Value = 1;
        GameField[_headY][_headX].Color = _colors[1];
        _lenght = 1;

        AddFood();
    }

    public void Start(object parametr)
    {
        InitGame();
        _gameState = GameState.Process;
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SnakeGame.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SnakeGame"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Змейка"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
      >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="0.1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Background="{Binding Color}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CellTemplate}" Background="Black">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" ItemsSource="{Binding GameField, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource GridTemplate}" >

        </ItemsControl>
        <Button 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Content="Начать игру" 
            Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
            Width="auto" 
            Height="auto" 
            Margin="5" 
            FontSize="12"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I just place my

```
GameField = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>();
```

in constructor.